# What does this '&' mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/1c85c5654a2ce1d43d4c64d98b928ff133d46406/lib/active_admin.rb#L95

What does the `&` (prefixed to `ActiveAdmin`) in this code mean?

```
def before_load(&block)
  ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe(
    ActiveAdmin::Application::BeforeLoadEvent,     
    &ActiveAdmin::Event.wrap_block_for_active_support_notifications(block)
  )
end
```

Comment: I believe it invokes the to_proc method on whatever gets returned.

Answer (score 4):

In functions `&` 'splats' blocks (also calls `to_proc` on it), similar to `*` for regular parameters.

That is somewhat equivalent to

```
def before_load(&block) # this binds provided block into block variable
  ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe(ActiveAdmin::Application::BeforeLoadEvent){|some_params_maybe|
    ActiveAdmin::Event.wrap_block_for_active_support_notifications(block).call(some_params_maybe)
  }
end
```

Comment: The important thing here is you don't have to know or care how many arguments that block needs.

Answer (score 2):

usually `&` calls `to_proc` method of the object, such as `gets.split.map(&:to_i)` is used to read line of integers, which is the same as `map { |e| e.to_i }`

In method arguments, it appears in the last arguments, meaning the code block you passed to, check the following code for details.

```
def g
    puts yield "g"
end

def h(block)
    puts block.call "h"
end

def f(&block)
    puts block.class        # => Proc
    puts block.call "f"     # => hello f
    g &block                # => hello g       passed as code block
    h block                 # => hello h       passed as proc
end

f { |x| "hello " + x }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Following article](http://www.skorks.com/2013/04/ruby-ampersand-parameter-demystified/) provides a good explanation on the use of '&' in Ruby:

**The Implicit Block**
Methods in Ruby can take arguments in all sorts of interesting ways. One case that’s especially interesting is when a Ruby method takes a block.

In fact, **all Ruby methods can implicitly take a block, without needing to specify this in the parameter list or having to use the block within the method body** e.g.:

```
def hello
end

hello do
  puts "hello"
end
```

This will execute without any trouble but nothing will be printed out as we’re not executing the block that we’re passing in. We can – of course – easily execute the block by `yielding` to it:

```
def hello
  yield if block_given?
end

hello do
  puts "hello"
end
```

This time we get some output:

```
hello
```

We `yielded` to the block inside the method, but the fact that the method takes a block is still implicit.

It gets even more interesting since Ruby allows to pass any object to a method and have the method attempt to use this object as its block. If we put an ampersand in front of the last parameter to a method, Ruby will try to treat this parameter as the method’s block. If the parameter is **already a Proc object**, Ruby will simply associate it with the method as its block.

```
  def hello
      yield if block_given?
    end

    blah = -> {puts "lambda"}

hello(&blah)
lambda
```

If the parameter is not a `Proc`, **Ruby will try to convert it into one (by calling to_proc on it) before associating it with the method as its block**.

```
def hello
  yield if block_given?
end

class FooBar
  def to_proc
    -> {puts 'converted lambda'}
  end
end

hello(&FooBar.new)
converted lambda
```

All of this seems pretty clear, but what if I want to take a block that was associated with a method and pass it to another method? We need a way to refer to our block.

**The Explicit Block**
When we write our method definition, we can explicitly state that we expect this method to possibly take a block. Confusingly, Ruby uses the ampersand for this as well:

```
def hello(&block)
  yield if block_given?
end

hello do
  puts "hello"
end
```

Defining our method this way, gives us a name by which we can refer to our block within the method body. And since our block is a `Proc` object, instead of `yielding` to it, we can `call` it:

```
def hello(&block)
  block.call if block_given?
end

hello do
  puts "hello"
end
```

**I prefer `block.call` instead of `yield`, it makes things clearer**. Of course, when we define our method we don’t have to use the name ‘block’, we can do:

```
def hello(&foo)
  foo.call if block_given?
end

hello do
  puts "hello"
end
```

Having said that; ‘block’ is a good convention.